# Getting error on printing array

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I got this code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Oblig3A{
    public static void main(String[]args){
    OrdAnalyse O = new OrdAnalyse();
    OrdAnalyse.analyseMet();
    }
}

class OrdAnalyse {
    public static void analyseMet() {
    Scanner Inn = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        File skrivFil = new File("Opplysning.txt");
        FileWriter fw= new FileWriter(skrivFil);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        Scanner lesFil = new Scanner("Alice.txt");
        int i=0;
        int totalOrd=0;
        int antUnikeOrd=0;

        String[] ordArray = new String[5000];
        int[] antallOrd = new int[5000];

        while(lesFil.hasNext()) {
        String ord = lesFil.next().toLowerCase();
        totalOrd++;
        boolean ut=false;
        int y=0;
        int z=0;

        for(i=0; i<ordArray.length; i++) {
            if (ord.equals(ordArray[i])) {
            antallOrd[i]++;
            ordFraFor=true;
            }
        }
        if(ordFraFor=false) {
            antUnikeOrd++;
            z=0;
            boolean ordOpptelling=false;

            while(ordOpptelling=false) {
            if(ordArray[z] == null) {
                ordArray[z] = ord;
                antallOrd[z]++;
                ordOpptelling=true;
            }
            z++;
            }
        }
        }



        System.out.println(ordArray);

            }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }
    }
}
```

And this is supposed to do some heavy counting while reading the words out of a file one by one. However, when I finally try to print the array to terminal just check whether it is okay or not, before I start working on making the program able to write it to a text-file, it just gives an error which reads:
[Ljava.lang.String;@163de20
But I do not know how and where to check for errors in this case? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error... This is what the default toString() implementation of the Object class returns...

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@163de20
```

Means:

- array of references ( `[L` )
- of type String ( `java.lang.String` )
- unique object ID

Code of Object.toString()

```
public String toString() {
  return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

What you shouldd do is to use a proper way to print:

- a loop

  ```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for(String s: myArray) {
      sb.append(s);
      if(sb.length()>0) {
         sb.append(',');
      }
  }
  System.println(s.toString());
  ```
- [Arrays.toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Comment: Thanks alot! It really helped, can I ask an addon-question? When it printed, it printed all over the terminal, okay enough, but all the entries where null?! :O

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arrays.toString()` to log your Array's contents

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ordArray));
```

If you want a formatted output you need to iterate over it using a good old `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ordArray.length; i++) {
   System.out.printf("ordArray[%d] = %s", i, ordArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is commonly considered to be a "mistake" of arrays in Java: arrays don't override `toString()`, sadly. What you see is [`Object`'s `toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
>
> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

---

A common workaround is to use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oldArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to print the array element by element.

ie.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < ordArray.length; i++)
        System.out.println(ordArray[i]);
```